# Received memory warning. Level=2 &Level =1 in cocos2d

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

I am getting "Received memory warning. Level=2 &Level =1 " while playing my game third time.
I have already cleared all texture that used in the game ?
what should i do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using instruments is probably a good first step to see how much memory you are allocating exactly and at what point in code execution those allocations are happening.  You'll probably also want to take a look for leaks in instruments.

If your're getting memory warnings after a third time playing seems like some memory is not being freed that probably should be.  Are you creating sprites, textures or other large pieces of data every time you play?